# $N \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes_{\varphi} (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ where $N$ is the normalizer of Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

Question: Suppose $p$ is prime, $P \subset S_p$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $S_p$ (the symmetric group on $p$ elements) and $N = N(P)$ is the normalizer of $P.$ Show that
$$ N \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}) \rtimes_{\varphi} (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} $$
and describe $\varphi$.

I understand the arguments given in some similar questions on this site for $|N|=p(p-1).$ However, I am not quite sure how to show what the question is actually asking. I wanted to use the semidirect recognition theorem, but that doesn't quite apply here, because **one** of the hypotheses of the recognition theorem is $H \cap K = 1$ if we want to conclude $G \cong H \rtimes_{\varphi} K$ where $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G.$ However, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \cap (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}.$ How can I proceed?

Comment: A $p$-Sylow subgroup of $S_p$  is just a cyclic subgroup generated by a $p$-cycle. And that viewpoint lets us see how to express the result in your question in a way that works in every $S_n$, not just for prime $n$: the normalizer of the subgroup of $S_n$ generated by an $n$-cycle has the semidirect product group structure you describe, with $p$ replaced by $n$.

Comment: You are *misusing* the recognition theorem by confusing isomorphism with equality: if there are subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$ and $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^\times$, that does not make them *equal* to those groups, so the intersection observation you make is a mistake. Two subgroups of order $2$ in a group are both isomorphic to $\mathbf Z/2\mathbf Z$: do you think that makes the subgroups *equal* to each other?

Comment: If you want to make progress on your problem, try to work out what the *actual* elements in the normalizer are. Hint: the subgroup of *powers* of a $p$-cycle normalizes itself and that provides a subgroup of the normalizer isomorphic to (but not at all equal to!) $\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z$.

Comment: Thank you, @KCd Dr. Conrad. I appreciate your hints and clarifications.